# Are the following ways to implement allocation/deallocation functions correct?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

In my notes the following code is provided as an example of a programm to allocate and deallocate
memory that doesn't work because the vett variable in the allocate function is local. The function is fixed by using a double pointer and doing the changes in the commented code

```
void allocate(double *vett, int n)            //void allocate(double **vett, int n);
{   printf("vett=%p\n",vett);                 // printf("vett=%p\n",*vett); 
    vett = (double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double)); //*vett = (double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    printf("vett=%p\n",vett);                 // printf("vett=%p\n",*vett); 
}
void freeit(double *vett) { free(vett); }

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  double *v=NULL;
  int i, size=atoi(argv[1]);
  allocate(v,size);                       // allocate(&v,size);
  printf("v=%p\n",v);                     //printf("v=%p, &v=%p\n",v,&v);
  
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    v[i]=i;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("v[%d]=%f\n",i,v[i]);
  
  freeit(v);
  return 0;
}
```

**My question is do we really need a double pointer to fix the code? I came up with the following solution:**

```
void* allocate(double *vett, int n)            //  I changed here
{   printf("vett=%p\n",vett);                 
    vett = (double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double)); 
    printf("vett=%p\n",vett);  
    return vett;                           //  I added this
}
void freeit(double *vett) { free(vett); }

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  double *v=NULL;
  int i, size=atoi(argv[1]);
  v=allocate(v,size);                       // I changed here
  printf("v=%p\n",v);                     
  
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    v[i]=i;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("v[%d]=%f\n",i,v[i]);
  
  freeit(v);
  return 0;
}
```

**Is my solution ok? If it is, is any of the solutions preferable over the other?**

**Additionaly in the following site  https://aticleworld.com/dangling-pointer-and-memory-leak/ I found the following functions, but I don't think the Memory_Allocate function is correct, since it returns a local variable ( pvHandle). Am I right?**

```
static unsigned int Allocate_Counter  = 0;
static unsigned int Deallocate_Counter  = 0;
void *Memory_Allocate (size_t size)
{
    void *pvHandle = NULL;
    pvHandle = malloc(size);
    if (NULL != pvHandle)
    {
        ++Allocate_Counter;
    }
    else
    {
        //Log error
    }
    return (pvHandle);
}
void Memory_Deallocate (void *pvHandle)
{
    if(pvHandle != NULL)
    {
        free(pvHandle);
        ++Deallocate_Counter;
    }
}
int Check_Memory_Leak(void)
{
    int iRet = 0;
    if (Allocate_Counter != Deallocate_Counter)
    {
        //Log error
        iRet = Memory_Leak_Exception;
    }
    else
    {
        iRet = OK;
    }
    return iRet;
}
```

Comment: *Is my solution ok?* Yes it is fine for actually getting allocated memory back to the caller. Returning the pointer is an alternate way to do it. But `vett` should not be passed into the function as the input value is effectively not used at all. Just use a local variable.

Comment: @ kaylum Which line of code is your last sentence referring to? Is there something to correct?

Comment: `void* allocate(double *vett, int n)` should be `double* allocate(int n)`. The `vett` parameter is unnecessary and the return value arguably should not be a void pointer. What you have is not technically wrong but can be improved.

Comment: The code for `Memory_Allocate` is just fine.  Returning the **value** of a local variable is perfectly okay.  What's bad is returning a **pointer to** a local variable.

Comment: @kaylum I see your point about the unnecessary ´*vett ´ argument, but why did you change the return type from ´void*´ to ´double*´, that would be limiting the allocation to double variables. By using a *void it can be typecasted to any type. What is wrong with that?

Comment: `sizeof(double)` Your function is hard coded to allocate `double`. If you want a generic allocator like `malloc` then your function needs to be passed the full buffer size and not the number of elements.

Comment: Also, you could of course pass in the number of elements and the size of one element. Like `calloc`.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge  Supposed I call Memory_Allocate(sizeof(double)) from main().  This function returns the pointer to the allocated memory in  pvHandle, that gets destroyed when the function ends because it is local. Then  I wouldn't be able to use the allocated space, would I?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: That's not correct.  The variable `pvHandle` gets destroyed, but you're not returning a pointer to `pvHandle`.  You're returning the value that `pvHandle` contained, which is a pointer to the memory that `malloc` allocated, and that memory hasn't been destroyed (only `free()` can do that).  Think about `int foo(void) { int x = 5; return x; }`.  This is perfectly fine - `x` gets destroyed but what is being returned is its value.

Comment: Never, never never, cast the returned value from `malloc()` (or `calloc`, or any of its friends)  That' a legacy from when there was no `void *` type in C, and it's very error prone.  When you cast, you tell the compiler you know what you are doing, and you don't, so don't cast, it's a bad habit.  Very bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is correct, in the case you return back a pointer, that pointer is the one received from `calloc()`.  And in that case there's no need for the double pointer.  In the first case, without returning the pointer with `return`, the problem is that the pointer you pass to the function is copied in, and the copy can be modified inside the function, but that copy is different than the value of the variable you got it from.

Now two hints:

- I have told you this in a comment to the question but: NEVER cast the result of `malloc()` and friends.  You hide several possible errors if you cast the value returned: if you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` the compiler will assume the function returns an `int` (wrongly, a pointer and a `int` are not the same size in 64bit architectures, and getting a 32 bit value will truncate your data to 32 bits, to later extend it to 64) and will generate code for getting an `int` that will be converted to a pointer (because of the cast, wrong again) with no warning from the compiler (because you have said with the cast *don't worry, I know what I'm doing*)
- You return a `void *` from your function, which returns the value of a variable that is of type `double *`, and do so without a cast, that illustrates how the `void *` can be automatically converted by the compiler, so making the cast from `malloc()` totally unnecessary.  But why don't return instead a `double *`, as you have already made the effort to convert a `void *` into a `double *`, just to convert it back to `void *`.  If you want a wrapper function to return arrays of `double`s, then return a `double *` in the function, and then you'll avoid the type conversion you do in the `return` statement, just to convert it again back to `double *` (which I guess this is what you want).

This applied to your code results in these comments:

```
/* return void *? Why did you convert it to double *? */
void* allocate(double *vett, int n)
       /* why pass a pointer if you are not using the value inside the function body? */
{   printf("vett=%p\n",vett); /* well you print it :$ */
    /* don't cast the automatic conversion, let the compiler do its work */                 
    vett = (double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double)); 
    printf("vett=%p\n",vett);  
    return vett; /* the double * stored in vett is converted to a void * to return it */
}

void freeit(double *vett) { free(vett); }

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  double *v=NULL;
  int i, size=atoi(argv[1]);
  v=allocate(v,size); /* and you convert it again to double * here */
  printf("v=%p\n",v);                     
  
...
```

so you get a `void *`, cast it to `double *` to be stored in a pointer variable, convert it to `void *` again to return the value to `main` and convert it again automatically to store it in `main`'s `v` variable.  My conclusion from this sample is that you never cast the value of `malloc`, and you should use the type `void *` as low as possible.  The standard library functions do it for reasons out of scope, and trying to emulate them is something you can try, but when you have a better understanding of pointers.  Until then, better never use `void *` pointers.  A general principle is that you should the proper types, you never had to cast them.  Casting should not be necessary (and it's almost never done in well written code) so better avoid casting as much as you can. The 80% of the errors come from bad casts, and the other 20% come from improperly defined types.  C is already a language too lazy in type management, don't make it more by overusing of casts.

In my opinion, your code should be:

```
double *allocate_doubles(int n)
{
    /* automatic conversion is done here only */
    double *vett = calloc(n, sizeof(double)); 
    printf("vett=%p\n", vett);  
    /* no conversion as vett is already of the function return type */
    return vett; 
}

void freeit(double *vett)
{
    free(vett);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  double *v = NULL;            /* use spaces, for readability */
  int i,                     /* this is more readable */
      size = atoi(argv[1]);

  /* and no conversion because both, allocate and v are the same type */
  v = allocate(v, size);
  printf("v=%p\n", v);                     
  
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    v[i] = i;

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("v[%d]=%f\n", i, v[i]);
  
  freeit(v);

  return 0;
}
```